# How to access particular column name in XlsxWriter through dictionary key?

Tags: python, dictionary, xlsx, xlsxwriter

[image: Excel file]

I want to excel file like in above image, with more than 100 columns,

```
row_header = ['Student_id', 'Student_name', 'Collage_name', 'From', 'To',
.........upto 100 column name]
```

**My Simple Question is how write flexible code, So if order of name change then, I don't have to write code again.**

For first row which contains the only column name only I write following code. This will create the first row.

```
for item in row_header:
    worksheet.write(row, col, item)
    worksheet.set_row(row, col)
    col += 1
```

Now problem I that, I am getting the list of dictionary, each dictionary contains the one student details, means each dictionary contains 100 key value.

```
student_list= 
[{collage_name: IIIT-A, Student_name:'Rakesh','Student_id':1,.....up to 100 key},
{collage_name: IIIT-G, Student_name: 'Shyam', 'Student_id':2, ........ up to 100 key}]
```

As you can see that key order is not matching with the column's name order. If I try to write like above it will take 100 line of code. So I am looking for solution where we can assign the cell value according to column value. How to use xlsxWrite through key -value dictionary, so that require to write less number of code..